# Reading integers separated by space

Tags: fortran

I have written a function that reads an array and returns it:

```
function read_array(f) result (arr)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: f
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: arr
    integer :: n, i

    read(f, *) n
    allocate(arr(n))
    do i = 1, n
        read(f, *) arr(i)
    end do
end function read_array
```

This function is supposed to read an array of integers from a file in unit `f` and return it as a pointer. The problem is that in the `do` loop, every `read` statement reads an entire line, rather than just 1 integer.

Here is how I want my file to look:

```
5
9 7 4 3 10
```

And here is how I have to lay it out currently:

```
5
9
7
4
3
10
```

So how can I make the `read` statement not consume an entire line and only read one number?

Comment: Fortran reads (in general) line based, so you probably don't need the loop and the read satement should be something like: `read(f, *) arr`.

Comment: @albert Thank you, it worked! Maybe you should post it as an answer, so that others who have the same question can see it easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fortran: Reading and printing 2D array from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961633/fortran-reading-and-printing-2d-array-from-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like

```
read(f,*)yourarray
```

should work for you